# will failing an exam in undergrad affect the persons chances of getting into a good phd program

Tags: phd, undergraduate, exams

let's say someone failed in a major subject in their end semester examination in their undergrad. that person had to retake the exam. will this affect the person's chance of getting into a good Ph.D. program.

Comment: a failed semester exam that i had to retake

Comment: So, more of a setback. Perhaps you should edit, and provide that detail as well. And, did you need to repeat the course, or just retake an exam but passed the course?  It is unclear as it is.

Comment: And registering for the site will make some interactions easier.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: just retake the exam and passed the course

Answer (score 0):

No single thing, especially something like that, would have much of any effect. In fact, it is  unlikely that anyone would know about it unless you tell them. If you pass the course it is all that really matters for later, though it contributes to your GPA.

If you have "squared it" with your professor, all the better. Nearly everyone stumbles and many take a fall before finding success. Put it behind you.